# How to display and change image on buttopTap in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

Image is not changing on the button tap.

I have over 100 images in asset folder. How to iterate over those images?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var tapCounter:Int = 1
    @State var images = [Image(systemName: "1_ArRehmanu"),Image(systemName: "3_AlMaliku"),
                         Image(systemName: "4_AlQudoos"),Image(systemName: "1_ArRehmanu"),Image(systemName: "3_AlMaliku"),Image(systemName: "4_AlQudoos"),Image(systemName: "3_AlMaliku"),
                         Image(systemName: "4_AlQudoos")]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action:{
                    self.tapCounter += 1
                    ForEach(0..<images.count){value in (images[value])
                        .resizable()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .frame(width:330, height:330)
                        .padding()
                    }
                },
                label:{
                    Text("Start")
                        .frame(width: 250
                               , height: 60, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.black)
                        .cornerRadius(8.0)
                        .padding()
                })
                Text("\(tapCounter) times")
                    
                    
                    .navigationTitle("Ninty Nine Names Of Allah")
                
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have you gone fully through [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)? Part of it covers this sort of situation.

Comment: `systemName:` constructor is for SF symbols only

Comment: You need to write Image("imageName"), instead of Image(systemName: "imageName").